# AngularJS keep objects in array even after subsequent Get Requests

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm implementing a messaging feature in my ionic app. in my inbox, i GET request an api that returns an array that has a data structure like this:

```
[{id:1, from_user:1, to_user:2, message:"hello", has_been_read:false}]
```

when I read the message the has_been_read value will change to true. The problem is when i go back to inbox and page reloads the items disappear

```
 $scope.insertProperty=function(){

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<$scope.users.length;j++){
                if($scope.users[i].id==$scope.messages[j].from_user)                 

                 $scope.users[i].message=$scope.messages[j].message;

            }
        }
    }

  //$scope.users0= [];
  $scope.users = [];

  $localStorage.messages = [];
  var getUser = function(id) {
        UserService.GetUserById(id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {
          data = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.users.push(data);  
            $scope.insertProperty();
            $localStorage.messages.push(data);
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete')
            console.log(angular.toJson($localStorage.messages))
        }).error(function(error, status) {
            alert(status);
            console.log(error);         
        });
    };

$scope.GetMyMessages = function(){
  UserService.GetMyMessages($localStorage.CurrentUser.id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token, -1, -1)
        .success(function (data) {
         console.log(data);       
         data = angular.fromJson(data);
         $scope.messages = data;
         angular.forEach(data, function(user){
                getUser(user.from_user)
         });

          }).
        error(function(error, status) {
          alert(status);
          console.log(error);         
      });
}

$scope.GetMyMessages();
})
```

In my Code i call my message service which i pass on -1/-1 which gets ALL in the list (they are begin/start indexes).. then i subcall to get User by id.. and merge 2 arrays so i could associate the user by its message.

The GetMessages service returns all has_been_read = false messages with unique from_user.. data structure is like this: [{id:1, from_user:1, to_user:2, message:"hello", has_been_read:false}]

The GetUserById then gets each from_user's information data structure is like this: [{id:1, username:"foo"}]

The insertProperty method puts the user and message together

Comment: Add some relevant code..

Comment: You are missing *a lot* of detail here.  first, it sounds like your server API is set to only deliver messages with `has_been_read:false`.  second, why are you getting a full page reload when navigating between your views?

Comment: not really getting  full page reload just for that particular page.. i'm doing  long polling on run.. because i don't have time to learn websockets yet, it does the job for the mean time

Comment: @Chrillewoodz added my code

Comment: I don't see how the code that you added to the question is related to the issue at hand.  You haven't shown the relevance of `has_been_read`, which seems to be the piece you suggest is causing the issue.  none of the code here shows where that property is changed, or if it is having an effect on the data coming from the server or the way the view is rendering the data.

Comment: @Claies that's exactly how i set it up... in the view i would ng-repeat="user in users"

Comment: exactly how you set what up?  you aren't showing what data is coming from the server, you aren't showing if you are getting ***ALL*** the messages from the server and filtering client side, or only getting ***some*** of the messages from the server with this code.

Comment: i see i'll put comments

Comment: also, it really seems crazy that every time the page loads, you are loading **all** the users and **all** the messages, and then looping through the arrays and pushing them together; I can only assume that you are actually filtering that down to the user that is actually viewing their messages; why would you send User A's client all the messages for User B, C, D, etc....?

Comment: @Claies it's the inbox.. so if user B, C, D wrote me a message.. i would see their last message in my inbox.. And that's how the backend developer created the API.. i can only make use of what he gave... the server only gives the last message i don't get ALL conversations and filter only the last

Comment: ok, so your latest update confirms my very first statement.  If your API returns ***only*** messages with `has_been_read=false`, then they aren't going to be loaded again when the page refreshes.  If you are hoping to rely upon what has already been downloaded, then you need to store the data in the local storage, and every page reload you'll have to decide if you want to use what is in local storage or make a fresh call to the server.

Comment: @Claies thanks.. i had thought i would have to use localStorage.. could you give an example code please.. I'm really new to programming

Comment: Right now, you seem to be storing your data (`$localStorage.messages.push(data);`) but on page load, you would actually have to check to see if there is data there, and merge your new data from the server with the old data in the local storage.

Comment: i see.. because i did console.log to see if it kept my old data in the localStorage on pageload, and old data was replaced by new.. so how is the condition fot that

Comment: instead of just doing a call to `$localStorage.messages.push(data);`, you'll need to fetch the `$localStorage.messages` first, merge them with the server data, and **then** push them into local storage.